# Python - Identify and combine data into one period per ID (using start and end date) where one period has been split across multiple rows

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

I have a data-frame as follows:

```
ID   Start Date  End Date   
200  01/01/2020  03/01/2020 
200  04/01/2020  06/01/2020 
200  07/01/2020  09/01/2020 
200  18/05/2020  20/05/2020 
350  24/05/2020  27/05/2020 
350  01/06/2020  02/06/2020
372  04/06/2020  07/06/2020 
372  08/06/2020  10/06/2020
```

For the first three records for ID 200 and for ID 372 I would like to combine those dates into one row. That is where the ID matches and the End Date is one day before the start date of a record with the same ID.

I would like this:

```
ID  Start Date  End Date
200 01/01/2020  09/01/2020
200 18/05/2020  20/05/2020
350 24/05/2020  27/05/2020
350 01/06/2020  02/06/2020
372 04/06/2020  10/06/2020
```

I'm more of an analytics bod than a data wrangler so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas can happily handle dates, but you should convert them in `pd.Timestamp` format. Then a `groupby` and `agg` should give the expected result. Possible code:

```
# First transform the date columns in datetime format
df[['SD', 'ED']] = df[['Start Date', 'End Date']].transform(
    pd.to_datetime, dayfirst=True)

# then shift the start date by one to detect contiguous rows
df[['ID1', 'SD1']] = df[['ID', 'ED']].shift()

# identify groups of rows to aggregate (same id and contiguous dates)
df['row_id'] = ((df['ID']!=df['ID1'])
                |(df['SD']!=df['SD1']+pd.offsets.Day(1))).cumsum()

# groupby agg is now enough...
result = df.groupby('row_id').agg(**{'ID': ('ID', min),
                'Start Date': ('Start Date', min),
                'End Date': ('End Date', max)}
                                  ).reset_index(drop=True)
```

It gives as expected:

```
    ID  Start Date    End Date
0  200  01/01/2020  09/01/2020
1  200  18/05/2020  20/05/2020
2  350  24/05/2020  27/05/2020
3  350  01/06/2020  02/06/2020
4  372  04/06/2020  10/06/2020
```

It this sounds like black magic, print the dataframe after each step to see what happens...

Comment: Thanks! Seems to work, I just had to sort my original data by ID and then Start Date.